# How to refresh the cache of PDF.js Viewer?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pdf, pdf.js

I've got a problem with our PDF.js Viewer plugin (pdfjs-viewer).

We have a PDF which needs to be displayed with the plugin, so far no problem. If we now replace the PDF with a new one --- it's a menu so it changes every week --- it still displays the old one. Even if we just delete the PDF on the site with the plugin you can't see any difference: the PDF is still there.

Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?

We implemented  the plugin like this:

```
[pdfjs-viewer url=path/to/menue/menue.pdf viewer_width=1100px viewer_height=1000px fullscreen=true download=true print=true openfile=true]
```

We are using PDF.js Viewer Version 1.2.

Comment: I have improved the text and formatting. I changed the title, please check if is appropiate. I also removed the chatting text because StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js Viewer does not cache any PDF files. However your hosting environment might, see http://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens#Server-side_Caching :

"This situation may also occur if you are using a Managed WordPress hosting plan. Many Managed WordPress hosting plans use server-side caching. If you are using a Managed WordPress service from your hosting provider and you are seeing this issue, you may want to see if they have an option to manually flush the cache. In many cases, your changes will immediately show up after flushing the cache."

Answer (score 0):

Just add a random query string to the end of the file URI as in:

```
cacheBuster: function() { 
    let qs="?param="; 
    qs += Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
    return qs; 
}
```